# Client side includes on local machine

Tags: javascript, html

I obviously can't use server side languages, this is just a page on my desktop.

I tried using AJAX with jquery, but I get the following error message

> Sorry but there was an error: 0 [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)" location: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js Line: 4"]

It has to do with the browser not loading scripts because it's hosted locally or something. So is there any way I can include files on a local machine without installing web server software?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you're doing exactly?

Comment: AJAX is not for opening local files, and reading them. All an ajax call is, is sending some data to some location, and JavaScript assumes the receiving party will know how to handle it. What you're doing, if I'm not mistaken is similar to walking to a door and shouting `sesame open thee`, works in fairy tales, but in the real world you need a gate keeper of sorts :)

Comment: I was mistaken.  @flem has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) error. You can't make http requests to third party sites (urls not on your domain). You would need to use a proxy to make requests to the page (or have the owner allow your site to make XSS requests).

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug of a library that I wrote the solve similar problem. We wanted to be able to splice HTML files for backend implementations without the overhead of a local HTTP server implementing server side includes. This library works on HTTP or local filesystem. But, as the repository README notes, you'll have to enable a `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to your Chrome runtime. Other browsers work out of box.

https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js

```
<div data-include="/path/to/include.html"></div>
```

The above will take the contents of `/path/to/include.html` and replace the `div` with it.